# Send the same bash process multiple commands

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I have the following code:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

function spawnInstance () {
  const c = cp.spawn('bash');
  return command => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      c.stdout.on('data', d => resolve(String(d || 'empty stdout.\n')));
      c.stderr.once('data', d => reject(String(d || 'empty stderr.\n')));
      c.stdin.write(`echo "${command}" | bash;`);  
      c.stdin.write('\n');
    });
  };
}

(async () => {
  const bash = spawnInstance();
  console.log(await bash('ls'));
  console.log(await bash('cd node_modules'));
  console.log(await bash('ls'));
})()
.catch(e =>
  console.error(e)
);
```

What I want to do is to reuse the same bash process, and get the stdout for each command that I run. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to start a new bash process for each command I run?

The problem is my code gets stuck on the `cd node_modules` command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can keep a bash process alive after a bash call and then re-enter the process with some new call. You can however run multiple bash commands after each other in the same process, e.g. by separating them with semicolons:

```
console.log(await bash('cd node_modules; ls'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://bitsofinfo-wordpress-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2015/01/17/executing-stateful-shell-commands-nodejs-powershell-bash-etc/amp/?amp_js_v=a6&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQHKAFQArABIA%3D%3D#aoh=16159461728228&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fbitsofinfo.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F01%2F17%2Fexecuting-stateful-shell-commands-nodejs-powershell-bash-etc%2F) states that now there is an NPM package that allows for a persistent bash process.

The github url:

https://github.com/bitsofinfo/stateful-process-command-proxy

Quote from the him homepage:

> This node module can be used for proxying long-lived bash process, windows console etc. It works and has been tested on both linux, os-x and windows hosts running the latest version of node.